# I am not able to connect Atlas MongoDB Cloud from a2hosting shared NodeJS hosting

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
var express = require("express");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
const uri = "<mongodb atlas connection string...>";

var app = express();
var port = 3000;
 
app.get("/sam/", (req, res) => {

    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connect(uri, { 
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true 
    }, 
    (err) => {
        if (!err) { 
            return res.status(200).send("I am Working");
         }
        else { 
            return res.status(200).send(err);
         }
    });

});

app.listen(3000, () => {
 console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});
```

Form local development environment, I am able to access and working fine.

Once I deployed to **a2hosting Node JS Shared hosting**, I am getting following error:

**{"message":"Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: [https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/","reason":{"type":"ReplicaSetNoPrimary","setName":null,"maxSetVersion":null,"maxElectionId":null,"servers":{},"stale":false,"compatible":true,"compatibilityError":null,"logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes":null,"heartbeatFrequencyMS":10000,"localThresholdMS":15,"commonWireVersion":null}}](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/%22,%22reason%22:%7B%22type%22:%22ReplicaSetNoPrimary%22,%22setName%22:null,%22maxSetVersion%22:null,%22maxElectionId%22:null,%22servers%22:%7B%7D,%22stale%22:false,%22compatible%22:true,%22compatibilityError%22:null,%22logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes%22:null,%22heartbeatFrequencyMS%22:10000,%22localThresholdMS%22:15,%22commonWireVersion%22:null%7D%7D)**

Also following is the Mongo DB Network Permission.
[image]

Comment: It's unlikely that anyone will be able to help - you've (correctly) removed the connection string, but that means that nobody can diagnose this

Comment: The most likely situation is that a2hosting are blocking the outgoing traffic. Please contact them for support.

Comment: @Tom Mettam Thanks for helping me, for providing suggestions. My issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to connect Atlas Cloud MongoDB from A2hosting, for this I raised a ticket and provided port number and connection details.

They resolved my issue quickly, by opened all the requested and opened Atlas MongoDB related ports and confirmed they are opened firewall wise at this time.

**Now I am able to connect Atlas Cloud MongoDB from my NodeJS Shared A2hosting hosting.**

Note: For security reason, I remove 0.0.0.0/0 from Atlas Mongo DB Network Permission, and added my shared hosting IP address.

I hope this post will help lot of developers to deploy NodeJS and Atlas Cloud Mongo DB application.

Comment: I don't think this really belongs here.. this is a specific configuration at that one hosting company

Comment: By default many container based hosting providers are supporting eg: heroku
From cPanel Shared hosting it will help.

Comment: Hey, I am also facing this issue. Can you please share with me what exactly is the port number and connection url that I need to provide to the support?

Comment: Send your Mongodb connection string with temp password to your support team. Port number is 27017. They will add the port number, after this we can able to connect.